# I just made a Facebook Account, already had a friend request awaiting?

Tags: facebook

I just made a Facebook account and I already have a friend request from some random person. How could they have added me as a friend before my account was even created?

Comment: More than likely they have you in their contacts and they invited you to join Facebook. Once you created an account Facebook remembered. I wouldn't worry about it too much; I get friend requests from strangers all the time. Just delete and move on.